# Making a pair of shared pointer and pushing in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I am trying to make a pair of shared pointer and push it into a list and get an error.
The error is at the line `list_of_objects_combination.push_back()`

What is wrong in my code?

> no matching function for call to
>   ‘Objects::Objects(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >&)’
>     { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

```
void MyClass::getCombination(std::vector<std::shared_ptr< Objects>> m_list_objects,
                                 std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Objects>, std::shared_ptr<Objects>>> &list_of_objects_combination) {

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr< Objects>>::const_iterator objectIterator = m_list_objects.begin();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Objects>>::const_iterator objectIteratorNext;

    for (; objectIterator < m_list_objects.end(); objectIterator++) {
        for (objectIteratorNext = objectIterator + 1; objectIteratorNext < m_list_objects.end();
             objectIteratorNext++) {

            list_of_objects_combination.push_back(std::make_pair(std::make_shared<Objects>(objectIterator),
                                                                 std::make_shared<Objects>(objectIteratorNext)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet could benefit from some type aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a pair from vector iterators: `std::make_shared<Objects>(objectIterator)`, instead of Objects/shared_ptrs. Try `std::make_pair(*objectIterator, *objectIteratorNext)`. That way you'll avoid another bug in your code, since you were trying to make new `shared_ptr` to existing objects, instead of copying existing ones. Currently, even `std::make_shared<Objects>(objectIterator)` to `std::make_shared<Objects>(objectIterator->get())` that'll create new shared_ptrs with separate ref counts which would lead to double deleting/UB.

Comment: Thank you.. Indeed I had to dereference the iterators before pushing it into the list. The cpp error was cryptic.